# Cordova/ionic app login not working in IOS 8

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, ionic-framework

One of my co-workers updated the version of IOS on the device (ipad) I am using to test my app to 8.1... Before the update, I was able to log into the app but not anymore. I did some research and found this article -> https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6538068?start=0&tstart=0

So I decided to update the device to the latest version of IOS (8.4) hoping it would fix the issue but the login still doesn't work. I've also tested the app using a different device with a lower version of IOS (7.1.2) and it works perfectly fine there... Has anyone experienced this before?

I'm using Ionic Framework - Cordova stack btw...

Comment: can you paste your error log's so that we will get an idea and if possible please paste your code in github or codepen

Comment: Hi @Anilkumar - basically the app is working and the web service too. The problem lies only with http request. It doesn't seem to go through the server. When you try to login, the spinner shows but nothing happens. The login works basically with other device except for an ipad that has been updated to IOS 8 recently. The http request even works there before the update. Another key thing is, the web server is being hosted using windows. What do you think? Btw, I don't think that there's something wrong with the app code but I'll try to set up a codepen or github later